# Error involving secondary use of cd.. in C code

Tags: c, windows, batch-file

```
  strcpy(strng, "cd.. ");
  strcat(strng, "& copy %cd%\\bin\\");
  strcat(strng, file);
  strcat(strng, " %cd%\\txt");
  system( strng );
```

Greetings, I've been working on file handling for C in windows, and unfortunately, I have run into this odd pickle. While I have gotten most of my code to work, including the issue I'm running into previously, "cd.." doesn't seem to be correctly going to the parent directory. Is there any word on why [or a quick and similar fix]?

Prior in the program it works in this short line of code:

```
  if (numLog > 8) {
    system("cd.. & cd txt & del *.txt");
    return errinit(); };
```

Comment: Be aware that if your directory names contain spaces, this whole thing will fall apart. Consider wrapping names in double-quotes. More generally, relying on calls to `system` does not make for particularly robust or portable code. Most of the time, this should be avoided.

Comment: Well aware! Thanks for the tips! @paddy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your effective string is

```
cd..& copy %cd%\bin\file %cd%\txt
```

Batch parses the entire line, then executes it, so `%cd%` is evaluated as its value **before** the `cd ..` is executed.

```
copy %cd%\..\bin\file %cd%\..\txt
```

should do what you appear to want.